# AngularJS and ColdFusion CFCs

Tags: coldfusion, angularjs, cfc

I'm trying to pick up AngularJS with a ColdFusion back end and am running into a few roadblocks.  I am modifying their "To Do" app http://angularjs.org/ with the CF Art Gallery database.  I'm trying to link a ColdFusion CFC to an Angular app using AJAX.

Below is my artists.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent>

<cffunction name="getArtists" access="remote" >
    <cfargument name="firstName" default="">
    <cfargument name="lastName" default="">

    <cfquery name="getArtists_sql" datasource="cfartgallery">
        SELECT
            firstname as text,
            lastname as done 
        FROM artists
        WHERE 0=0
    <cfif firstName neq "">
        AND ucase(firstname) like ucase('%#FIRSTNAME#%')
    </cfif>
    <cfif lastName neq "">
        OR ucase(lastname) like ucase('%#LASTNAME#%')       
    </cfif>
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn getArtists_sql>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

I call the CFC using AngularJS with the following code:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('cfc/artists.cfc?method=getArtists&returnformat=json').
        success(function (response) {
            $scope.todos = data.DATA;
    }).
        error(function (data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
        });
}
```

I know that I get a response back.  Below is the JSON string Chrome's developer tools returns for me:

```
{
"COLUMNS":
    ["TEXT","DONE"],
"DATA":[
    ["Aiden","Donolan"],
    ["Austin","Weber"],
    ["Elicia","Kim"],
    ["Jeff","Baclawski"],
    ["Lori","Johnson"],
    ["Maxwell","Wilson"],
    ["Paul","Trani"],
    ["Raquel","Young"],
    ["Viata","Trenton"],
    ["Diane","Demo"],
    ["Anthony","Kunovic"],
    ["Ellery","Buntel"],
    ["Emma","Buntel"],
    ["Taylor Webb","Frazier"],
    ["Mike","Nimer"]
]}
```

This doesn't look like the notation Angular used in their demo:

```
[
{text:'learn angular', done:true},
{text:'build an angular app', done:false}
]
```

Can someone point me to the right direction as to how I can go about getting this to work properly?  Ideally, I would like to keep the CFC intact so that in can be reused for a different application so the JSON manipulation would have to be done in the Javascript end.

Comment: What exactly is your question? BTW, your success callback is not referencing response data correctly. It should be `function (response) { $scope.todos = response.data.DATA; }`.

Comment: Explicitly stated, my question would be "How do I replace the information from AngularJS's TODO tutorial with one coming from the artist.cfc?  I have tried the `function(response) {$scope.todos = response.data.DATA;}` and I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA' of undefined`

Comment: My bad, I've mistaken the explicit `promise.success` method (which feeds the callback with data and status parameters) with `promise.then` method which feeds the callback(s) with response object, which has a data property. But in that case, your callback should be `function(data) {$scope.todos = data.DATA;}` given that your actual ajax response body really returns the JSON that you posted in your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Coldfusion uses a different JSON notation than you may be used to. The column names are stored in one array, while the data is stored in another. The solution we implemented involved changing the CFquery to an array. Then JSONEncoding that array.

You will need this function here:

```
<cffunction name="QueryToArray" access="public" returntype="array" output="false"hint="This turns a query into an array of structures.">
    <cfargument name="Data" type="query" required="yes" />

    <cfscript>
        // Define the local scope.
        var LOCAL = StructNew();

        // Get the column names as an array.
        LOCAL.Columns = ListToArray( ARGUMENTS.Data.ColumnList );

        // Create an array that will hold the query equivalent.
        LOCAL.QueryArray = ArrayNew( 1 );

        // Loop over the query.
        for (LOCAL.RowIndex = 1 ; LOCAL.RowIndex LTE ARGUMENTS.Data.RecordCount ; LOCAL.RowIndex = (LOCAL.RowIndex + 1)){

        // Create a row structure.
        LOCAL.Row = StructNew();

        // Loop over the columns in this row.
        for (LOCAL.ColumnIndex = 1 ; LOCAL.ColumnIndex LTE ArrayLen( LOCAL.Columns ) ; LOCAL.ColumnIndex = (LOCAL.ColumnIndex + 1)){

        // Get a reference to the query column.
        LOCAL.ColumnName = LOCAL.Columns[ LOCAL.ColumnIndex ];

        // Store the query cell value into the struct by key.
        LOCAL.Row[ LOCAL.ColumnName ] = ARGUMENTS.Data[ LOCAL.ColumnName ][ LOCAL.RowIndex ];

        }

        // Add the structure to the query array.
        ArrayAppend( LOCAL.QueryArray, LOCAL.Row );

        }

        // Return the array equivalent.
        return( LOCAL.QueryArray );

    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

And then your return will look like:

```
 <cfreturn SerializeJson(QueryToArray(getArtists_SQL),true)>
```

The thing to remember, is that a CFquery object contains other properties like recordcount...and most likely, the JS only wants the data. I don't know if there is a more elegant solution to this, but this is the solution we landed on when we were having a similar problem with JQgrid.

Comment: Well, that changed the JSON response from the CFC to `{"ROWCOUNT":15,"COLUMNS":["TEXT","DONE"],"DATA":{"TEXT":["Aiden","Austin","Elicia","Jeff","Lori","Maxwell","Paul","Raquel","Viata","Diane","Anthony","Ellery","Emma","Taylor Webb","Mike"],"DONE":["Donolan","Weber","Kim","Baclawski","Johnson","Wilson","Trani","Young","Trenton","Demo","Kunovic","Buntel","Buntel","Frazier","Nimer"]}}`, but it's still not like how the tutorial had the data.

Comment: @Chester Too right you are. My apologies. I will update my answer.

Comment: After thinking about it, I too have come to that same conclusion, albeit in a different way.  I really wanted to keep the CFC clean of any JSON modifications so that the CFC can be reused, but I figured it would be easier to modify / add any CFCs in the future than it is to do the javascript.  That being said, I used https://github.com/iknowkungfoo/ArrayCollection and wrapped the entire query to what it's supposed to be.  Thanks for your help.  Now I have to figure out how to get the response back to display in my view.

Comment: @Chester nothing can stop you to add a third argument to your CFC `<cfargument name="returnType" default="">` and check if it is "json" then use the code above to return good JSON to your Angular app.

Answer (score 3):

To go along with the above answer from Blaise.
The queryToArray I use looks at the query object's columnList.
This is so the case of the column aliases is preserved. Otherwise it will be all caps in your JSON

```
/**queryToArray
*  utility method to keep the code dry.
*  @hint does exactly what the name says, take a query, makes it an array of stucts
*  @hint columnLabels pass in a list of columnLabels to just return those columns
*/
public array function queryToArray(required query data, any columnLabels=false){
    var columns = listToArray(arguments.data.columnList);
    if(arguments.columnLabels != false){
            columns = listToArray(arguments.columnLabels);
    }

    var queryArray = arrayNew(1);

    for(i=1; i <= arguments.data.RecordCount; i++){

            row = StructNew();
            for (j=1; j <= ArrayLen(columns); j++){
                columnName = columns[j];
        row[columnName] = arguments.data[columnName][i];
            }
            arrayAppend(queryArray, row);
    }
    return(queryArray);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use this helper function in javascript to get query as (common) key-value objects array.

```
    function CFQueryParser(data) {
        let items = [];
        Object.keys(data.DATA).forEach((i) => {
            let item = {};
            Object.keys(data.COLUMNS).forEach((j) => {
                item[data.COLUMNS[j]] = data.DATA[i][j];
            });
            items.push(item);
        })
        return items;
    }
```